# Scrolling page id when Div id is just displayed from display:none to display:block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html pages the login and homepage. I have a condition upon logging in of a user. example is when he/she login using temporary password the url of redirecting page will be `home.html?change=yes#focuschange` Then on my home page when the url `change` == `"yes"`, it will hide the other div id's(home-wrapper). Then show the `focuschange` div id. And should be scrolled to the said div id. But upon loading the home page it just hide other div and show the `focuschange` div but not **scrolling** to it. It just display at the bottom. When I reload the page it will now scroll as I wanted. Why is that? I tried using `scrollIntoView()` and `animate scrollTop` but the same problem.

The structure of my html is like this:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block">
        <div id="home-wrapper"></div> //this will hide upon page load (by default it will show)
        <div id="profile-wrapper"> // this will show upon page load (by default it will hide)
            <div id="info"></div>
            <div id="focuschange">
               <form></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery function in home page:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam){
                var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
                {
                    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
                    {
                        return sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }

            }

            var urlvar = GetURLParameter('change');
            if (urlvar == 'yes'){

                $('#home-wrapper').hide();
                $('#profile-wrapper').show();

                setTimeout(function(){
                $("#newpass").focus();   
                }, 200);
            }
```

Is there a problem of scrolling a div id when it just displays upon loading the page?

What should be the approach in this scenario?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what your issue is but it looks like you are trying to use "anchors" with hashes to achieve smooth scrolling. Is this the case?

Comment: @Piercey4 Yes, I just want to scroll the page to the id on my url which is `#focuschange`

Answer (score 0):

you may want to change your line that is;

```
var urlvar = GetURLParameter('changepassword');
```

to

```
var urlvar = GetURLParameter('change');
```

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong variable. I update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jquery you can use jquery to perform the scroll.

Here is a `css-tricks` link that does exactly automatically on link clicks.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

If all you need is for this to happen on page load then you can do:

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#focuschange').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I already tried it, it only works when I reload again the page. I am thinking that maybe because it just show the before hide div id? What do you think?

Comment: Have you wrapped the scrolling part in a $(document).ready(function(){}) ??
it seems that you are trying to scroll to an element that isn't yet in the DOM...